# Post Data from MCV is not calling JS function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi i want to post just a simple string to a controller action in asp.net mvc5.

Im trying to do this for hours and cant find a solution on how it works.

I have tried many different solutions without one of them working in how I want.
For hours...

I have a simple view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rollen und Rechte";
}


<form>
    <table cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td>Rollenname:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Name" id="roleNameVal" />Rollenname</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />

    <label id="resultLabel"></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn_click" />
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
</form>

@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btn_click').click(function ()
    {
        alert("jas");
        var val1 = $('#roleNameVal').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/Create/Role",
            data: { "val1": val1 },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
}
```

The thing is that the function is never called.
What is wrong here?

And... in the next step I want to update `div id mydiv`
How can I change that without return a complete view in the controller and force a reload?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: use the web console on your browser to check if any visible errors when the button is clicked. it's possible jquery is not defined.

Comment: The browser's debug console will verify this. It looks like you are doing a standard form request and any ajax request would be lost. Start by removing `type="submit"` and making that an ordinary button `<button type="button">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis right before your closing `</script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btn_click').click(function ()
    {
        alert("jas");
        var val1 = $('#roleNameVal').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/Create/Role",
            data: { "val1": val1 },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        })
    }**)**
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `button click event` use the following

```
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function (event) {
      alert("jas");
      var val1 = $('#roleNameVal').val();
      $.ajax({
         type: "post",
         url: "/Create/Role",
         dataType: "JSON",
         data: new FormData(this),
         processData: false,
         contentType: false,
         success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
         error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
        }
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax.BeginForm of mvc

like this :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("YourActionName", "YourControllerName", new AjaxOptions {
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, //target element(#mydiv) will be replaced
    UpdateTargetId = "mydiv"  
}))
{
   <table cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td>Rollenname:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Name" id="roleNameVal" />Rollenname</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />

    <label id="resultLabel"></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn_click" />
}
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

and in yourController :

```
public PartialViewResult YourActionName(string name)
{
   return PartialView("_YourPartialView");
}
```

_YourPartialView is a partial View that you want to return replace it with "mydiv" And how to make it with VIEW is the same

if your partial view has a model you should do this :

```
return PartialView("_YourPartialView",yourModel);
```

Comment: So if i understood it correctly i should return the partialview like that?

``public PartialViewResult YourActionName(string name)
{
   return PartialView("myDiv");
}
`
Because this is looking for a view with the name myDiv

Comment: _yourPartialView as i said is a view (the partialview that name is "_yourPartialView.cshtml") that you want replace it with "mydiv" tag . you should create it.